# How to add a click function to an imported component in Vue

Tags: vuejs2

So I have a Vue2 app. I have create a component "u-button"

when i import this and use it in another component, I want to be able to add a click function to it. However at the moment it looks for a function on the u-button component rather than the component it is being used in.

so for example, in the below if i click the first button nothing happens, if i click the second button i get the console log.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <u_button @click="clicked">Click me</u_button>
        <button @click="clicked">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import u_button from '../components/unify/u_button'

    export default {
        components: {
            u_button
        },
        methods: {
            clicked() {
                console.log("Working!");
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

However if i add a method on the u-button component, then it calls that. So how can i get my below example to work ? The only thing I can think of is to wrap it in another div and add the click function to that. but I'm wondering if there is a better way?? I dont want to use events to do this either as that gets messy very quickly.

As you can imagine having a reusable button that when clicked always performs the same function is a bit pointless.

Comment: uses `<u_button @click.native="clicked">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue v-on:click does not work on component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the nature of components for example if we had a (virtual) iframe component which had a button in it and we'd like to detect `click` event on it we might name the event click and listen for it in the parent component; therefore, Vue introduced a feature called event modifiers for example in Vue, We have `.native` modifier (you can read more about the Vue modifiers [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on))

Now, to make your code work, You should add a `.native` after `@click` like this:

```
<u_button @click.native="clicked">Click me</u_button>
```

By the way, it's better to develop a naming convention for yourself It'd become handy when your projects get larger.