# v-on:click not working bootstrap

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Initially I thought this was an issue with how I was using the `@click` directive according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component). I added the `.native` to the directive and my method is still not getting invoked.

I know this is bootstrap as if I use a normal `<button>` then the method is invoked as expected.

There are no errors in the logs so it is just as if the element is not registering the directive?

**UpcomingBirthdays.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ section_title }}</h1>
        <b-card style="max-width: 20rem;"
                v-for="birthday in birthdays.birthdays"
                :key="birthday.name"
                :title="birthday.name"
                :sub-title="birthday.birthday">
            <b-button href="#"
                    @click.native="toWatch(birthday, $event)"
                    variant="primary">Watch
            </b-button>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
        name: "UpcomingBirthdays",
        data: () => {
            return {
                section_title: "Upcoming Birthdays",
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toWatch: (birthday, event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("watched called");
                console.log(birthday.name);
                console.log(`BEFORE: ${birthday.watch}`);
                birthday.watch = !birthday.watch;
                console.log(`AFTER: ${birthday.watch}`);
            }
        },
        computed: mapState([
            "birthdays",
        ]),
    };
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Worth mentioning that when using HTML5 `<button>`, I do not have to append the `.native` property to the `@click` directive.

**EDIT 2**

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l58oxvxjvl) I created to replicate this error. I would expect an error here to say `BirthdaysApi` is not defined but I am not getting anything when the button is clicked.

Comment: You probably have to pass `$event` as the first argument: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers. If that does not work, can you create an MCVE to show us a working example? If you need to use your code as-is, codesandbox.io might be the place to create a proof-of-concept example.

Comment: @Terry that is not the problem as I have attempted that way before. I have made a codesandbox and will edit my question to include

Comment: .native only matters for form submissions. It will do nothing for a normal button click outside of a form.

Comment: `[Vue warn]: The computed property "birthdays" is already defined in data.

found in

---> <UpcomingBirthdays> at /src/components/UpcomingBirthdays.vue
       <App> at /src/App.vue
         <Root>`

Comment: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `href="#"` from your buttons (this makes the Bootstrap `b-button` component render your buttons as anchors) and it's working as expected:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0yj3vwll7

Edit:

Apparently this is intentional behaviour from the authors, a decision I disagree upon. What they are doing is apparently executing `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` so any additional listener isn't triggered.

> https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1146