# Vue on:click doesn't work on vuikit icon

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuikit

**How to listen a click on a vuikit icon ?**

So this is how we are supposed to listen for a native click event [Vue v-on:click does not work on component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component) but that doesn't seem to work for the icons in https://vuikit.js.org/
has anyone faced this?

Given:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div><vk-icons-cog v-on:click.native="onClick"></vk-icons-cog ></div> // doesn't work
  <test-cmp v-on:click="onClick"></test-cmp> // works
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is what you want, but the code below works for me.

```
<vk-icon icon="cog" v-on:click="onClick"></vk-icon>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/kkn095v0qv

Comment: awesome, seems to be related to the instantiation then.
 <vk-icons-cog v-on:click="onClick"></vk-icons-cog > //doesn't work
    <vk-icon icon="cog" v-on:click="onClick"></vk-icon> // works

Comment: I added this question regarding instantiation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201826/error-instantiating-a-viukit-icon

Comment: Umm.. maybe it is related to the version? I used the latest version and both worked for me...

Comment: Ohh, you mean they both render ... yeah and you are right I just checked the version of my vuikit library and it's not the latest, testing it with the version I'm using also fails on the sandbox. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean. Sorry for the misleading word