# Error instantiating a viukit icon

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuikit

Given:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuikit from 'vuikit'
import VuikitIcons from '@vuikit/icons'

Vue.use(Vuikit)
Vue.use(VuikitIcons)
```

...

Trying to instantiate an icon like this doesn't work:

```
  <vk-icon icon="cog" v-on:click="onClick"></vk-icon> // doesn't work
```

error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

I'm only able to instantiate it like this:

```
<vk-icons-cog  v-on:click.native="onClick"> // does work
```

is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Issue related to version 0.6.2 it works fine on 0.8.5