# Can't toggle state when clicking on component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, state, dom-events

I trying to toggle state when I click on particular element

```
<script>
import ArrowSwitcher from '@/components/ui/ArrowSwitcher.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ArrowSwitcher
  },
  data () {
    return {
      showContent: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switcher () {
      this.showContent = !this.showContent
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<span class='targeting-global__name' @click='switcher'>
Some Text
    <ArrowSwitcher :showContent='showContent'/>
  </span>
```

When I stick event on parent element (just html, not other component) it works

Surprisingly this approach not changing state at all!
Why?

```
<span class='targeting-global__name'>
    Targeting Global
    <ArrowSwitcher :showContent='showContent' @click='switcher'/>
  </span>
```

I want to stick click event only to Arrow switcher component instead of whole text

Comment: You can't do a normal `v-on:click` (`@click`) on custom components. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind native events on components you have to use the following syntax:

```
<ArrowSwitcher :showContent='showContent' @click.native='switcher'/>
```

Here's the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 1):

You should watch the showContent using `computed` property:

```
export default {
...,
computed: {
  showContent: function () {
    return showContent
  }
}
```