# Why function doesn't work with a button component but does with a button html tag in VUE js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a VUE component button and tried to associate a v-on:click function, but it didn't work. Then I substituted it for an HTML button and it did work. I need to understand why.

I made this button component, which was loading ok on it's parent

```
    <template>
    <button v-on:click="action">{{ name }}</button>
    </template>

   <script>
   export default {
   name: "Appbutton",
   data: function() {
   return {};
   },
   props: {
   name: String,
         }
   };
   </script>
```

The code didn't fail when loaded by its parent:

```
          <template>
          <form class="login-form" action>
            <label for="email">Register E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email" />
            <label for="password">Register Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" v-model="password" />
            <div class="button-group">
             <AppButton action="register" name="Login" />
             <AppButton action="register" name="Login with Google" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </template>

        <script>
        import AppButton from "@/components/AppButton";
         export default {
          name: "RegisterForm",
          data() {
            return {
              email: "",
              password: "",
              show: true
            };
          },
          methods: {
            register: function(e) {
              console.log("registered");
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          },
          components: {
            AppButton
          }
        };
        </script>
```

When pressed the "Login" button, it reloaded the page with the parameters email and password in the URL but the console.log was not displayed nor triggered anywhere. I tried sending the "register" function as a prop to the AppButton.vue but it had the same behaviour.

It only worked when I substituted the button component for a regular HTML button. Now it works as expected.

I just need to understand why is this behaviour, and how should I have to solve it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You probably want to use `@click.native` instead of `@click`.
Also have a look at this link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component

Comment: Thank you I wasn't looking the right way. It is completely explained there. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to add `action` as a prop to your AppButton, then you need to bind your click event using :click="register".

I made a sandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-button-action-c5kun

Answer (score 0):

Happens because of form `submit` is not prevented.
Put `@submit.prevent` on `form` tag

```
<form class="login-form" action @submit.prevent>
  <label for="email">Register E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email" />
  <label for="password">Register Password</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" v-model="password" />
  <div class="button-group">
     <AppButton action="register" name="Login" />
     <AppButton action="register" name="Login with Google" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This should do. I will also look at the article that Utsav recommended since I am also interested in knowing why.