# button v-on:click not functioning in Vue Native

Tags: vue-native

I'm trying to get `button v-on:click` to work in Vue Native but it is not updating the variable as expected.  Here is the code in the App.vue file of a basic project:

```
<template>
    <view class="container">
        <button v-on:click="count += 1" title="Add 1" />
        <text>{{ counter }}</text>
    </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

The value of `counter` is always showing as 0, even after clicking the "Add 1" button several times.  Why isn't `button v-on:click` working in Vue Native?

**EDIT #1:**
As @Suoakira pointed out the button code was incorrect so it has been updated follows:
`<button v-on:click="counter++" title="Add 1" />`
However, the value of `counter` is still always showing 0, even after clicking the "Add 1" button.  Why isn't this working in Vue Native?

**EDIT #2:**
I have still not found a way to get `v-on:click` to work in Vue Native in the `button` tag.  However, the following alternative works.  It is further developed than the original post.  It demonstrates two different ways to work with `:on-press` in `touchable-opacity`.  If someone knows how to write the equivalent using `v-on:click` and the `button` tag in Vue Native, I'd sure like to see that solution.  In the meantime -

```
<template>
    <view class="container">      
        <touchable-opacity class="button" :on-press="() => counter++">
            <text class="button-text">Add 1</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
        <touchable-opacity class="button" :on-press="addTwo">
            <text class="button-text">Add 2</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
        <touchable-opacity class="button" :on-press="resetCounter">
            <text class="button-text">Reset</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
        <text>{{ counter }}</text>
    </view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTwo: function() {
      this.counter += 2;  
    },
    resetCounter: function() {
      this.counter = 0;      
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #FFCE00;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.button-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component.

Answer (score 0):

Your data property is counter, but you are updating count on click.

Comment: That is a very good point.  I updated the code and made an update to the original post.  However, `v-on:click` is still not adding 1 to the `counter` variable when clicked.

Comment: Seems like Eric day has posted the correct solution :) . Hopefully that works

`v-on:click.native="counter++"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.  If I find a solution, I'll be sure to post it.

Answer (score 0):

please try with `:on-press="test"` instead of `v-on:click`