# Is it component definition in vue? How do I find whether it is a component by looking at the code?

Tags: vue.js

When I search for something I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component)

Here, `something`, I believe it is `component`, is defined as below.

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    testFunction: function (event) {
      console.log('test clicked')
    }
  },
  components: {
    Test
  }
}
```

As per the documentation, I came across [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components)

```
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue'
import BaseIcon from './BaseIcon.vue'
import BaseInput from './BaseInput.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    BaseButton,
    BaseIcon,
    BaseInput
  }
}
```

I really not sure, whether `app` is a component which contains `Test`. Is it the component definition in `export`? How do we understand that is a component from vue code?

Is it only by the below ways?

1. Vue.component
2. components in Vue instance
3. Not sure - the `export default` way?

I understand that I sound different because it is Javascript. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are conventionally, three different types of components in Vue JS.

- Root Component
- View Component
- Normal Component

In a conventional structure the Root component is named 'app' and is passed to the Vue instance when initializing the App for the first time. This component can not be imported and reused inside other components as it will cause a recursive effect. For example this [App.vue](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/App.vue) file is a Root component. It is used inside this [main.js](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/main.js) file and passed to the Vue instance using `new Vue`.

The View components are dynamically added or removed from the Root component based on the route. They are written and act as normal component and are only used for Vue router `component` property. For example the `Home` and `Comments` components inside this [Router index file](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/router/index.js) are known as View components. They are passed inside the route objects as components inside individual routes. When the app navigates to that particular route, the `<router-view>` template inside the [App.vue](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/App.vue) file gets replace with the template of the corresponding View component.

Normal components can be used anywhere and are imported by other components. They can be imported inside the View components as well as the Root components. For example, in root component [App.vue](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/App.vue) we see the component `Navbar` is used. In View component [Comments.vue](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/components/Comments.vue) the [Replies](https://github.com/shakib779/hacker-news-site-in-vue/blob/master/src/components/Replies.vue) component is used.

All these components are identical in declaration and behavior but differ in usage.

Comment: Can you add a reference or an example which one each is?

Comment: Added some examples to the answer @Gibbs