# blur on custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom component which is basically an input with some styles. I want to alert something when the user focuses out of the component. I added @blur and tabindex but it still doesn't alert anything. what's wrong with my code here? the custom component doesn't emit anything on blur though

```
<template>
  <custom-component v-model="email" @blur="showSomething" tabindex="0"/>
</template>

<script>
export default{
 data(){
  return{
    email
  };
 },
 methods{
  showSomething(){
    alert('yes')
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like this Q&A also contains a couple answers to your question: [Vue v-on:click does not work on component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a custom component, you need to manually specify events that it should emit, using [Vue's `$emit()` instance method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit).

I don't know what your underlying component code looks like, but it can be as simple as adding `$emit('blur', $event)` to your input's blur handler:

```html
<input v-model="xxx" ... @blur="$emit('blur', $event)">
```

([`$event` is just special Vue syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) for referencing the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can omit it if you don't need access to it– just call `$emit` with only the first argument: `$emit('blur')`.)

If you already have a handler/ method being called on the blur event in that component, then you can alternatively add `$emit` into that method, just don't forget the `this`:

```js
methods: {
  ...
  blurHandler() {
    ...
    this.$emit('blur');
    ...
  },
  ...
},
```

---

There are [other solutions to this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components), but explicitly calling `vm.$emit()` is probably the most straightforward and clear.

Comment: it's a component from a library. i can't make any change to the component

Comment: @allhopelost You should give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component/41476882#41476882) solution a look this, it uses [Vue's `.native` event modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

Comment: done that. didn't work. most probably because there's a label element too in the custom component, not just input..

Comment: Your last resort is probably `$listeners` then, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475447/vue-v-onclick-does-not-work-on-component/61734142#61734142), and [further down under `.native`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) in the docs. You might also double check that the library itself doesn't provide any way to get a blur event or provide some equivalent too; that's a very standard event, it's pretty strange that they left it out altogether.

Comment: @allhopelost You can only listen to events that the component emits. If the component does not emit a `blur` event, using `@blur` will not have any effect. What component library are you using?

Comment: its a in house company library @tony19