# Custom Dropdown input not triggering blur event

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, blur, custom-component

I have a custom dropup component that I am building and I find myself running into some very weird issues with it. The biggest one being the blur event, which doesnt seem to be firing when I click outside of the input.

Basically I just want the options elements to hide on blur, if there is no `localValue` then reset the component back to the **Initial View** and if there IS a `localValue` set it to the **Selected State**, keeping the value in there.
I'm really not sure where I am going wrong here.

**---Designs---**

**Initial State**

[image]

**Toggled State**

[image]

**Selected State**

[image]

I've made a **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropup-input-mg6enz?file=/src/App.vue:0-992)** so you can see this thing live.

I would love if anyone has any ideas on how I can fix this and get the blur event happening properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

**NOTE**
I've tried putting the blur event on the input itself, since it makes sense I think that when clicking outside of the input, it should close everything. `optionsAreVisible.value = true` does work to close it, but I dont think just blurring the input is the way to go here. I think I still want to have the blur on the entire element.

**Extra Issues:**

1. Is my `:key="buttonKey"` and `buttonKey.value++` combination to reset the component the proper way to do this? It seems hacky and a bit wrong to me, but I am not totally sure!
2. How to get the **Initial State** and **Selected State** to be the same size? The **Selected State** has a few more elements in it, but the design has them as the same width and I've been having trouble with getting that to work properly without hardcoding widths (which I dont want to do)
3. Not sure if this is a bug with Codesandbox, but `:class="[localValue === '' ? '_hide' : '', '_input-active-delete']"` line doesnt seem to be working so I have to do a v-if, which is not what my actually codebase uses. ANy idea what could be going on there?
   [image]

**SelectModelInput**

```
<template>
  <div :key="buttonKey">
    <div
      style="position: relative; width: 100%"
      tabindex="-1"
      @blur="() => closeDropdown()"
    >
      <div class="_input" @click="() => toggleDropup()">
        <p
          v-if="selectModelVersionIsVisible"
          class="_input-active-select-model"
        >
          Select Model
        </p>
        <div v-if="!selectModelVersionIsVisible" class="_input-active">
          <p class="_input-active-op-real">OP-REAL</p>
          <input
            v-model="localValue"
            :class="[
              localValue !== '' && !optionsAreVisible ? '_bg-change' : '',
              '_input-active-input',
            ]"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type to Search"
          />
          <button
            v-if="localValue"
            :class="[localValue === '' ? '_hide' : '', '_input-active-delete']"
            @click="() => clearLocalVal()"
          >
            <svg
              style="width: 18px"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="none"
              stroke="#A5B0CB"
              stroke-width="2"
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              class="feather feather-x"
            >
              <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
              <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Transition name="fade">
        <div
          v-if="optionsAreVisible && filteredOptions.length !== 0"
          class="_options"
        >
          <a
            v-for="option in filteredOptions"
            :key="option.model"
            class="_option"
          >
            <div class="_option-inner" @click="selectOption(option.model)">
              <p class="_option-inner-model">{{ option.model }}</p>
              <p class="_option-inner-date">{{ option.date }}</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </Transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { computed, defineComponent, ref, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  emit: ["input"],
  props: {
    value: { type: String },
    models: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        { model: "Test v1", date: "Jul.5.2022" },
        { model: "Test v2", date: "Jul.6.2022" },
        { model: "Test v3", date: "Jul.8.2022" },
      ],
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const localValue = ref(props.value);
    watch(localValue, (newVal) => {
      emit("input", newVal);
    });
    const buttonKey = ref(0);
    const optionsAreVisible = ref(false);
    const selectModelVersionIsVisible = ref(true);
    const options = ref(props.models);
    const filteredOptions = computed(() => {
      const filteredOptions = options.value.filter((option) =>
        option.model.toLowerCase().includes(localValue.value?.toLowerCase())
      );
      return filteredOptions;
    });
    function toggleDropup() {
      console.log("toggle Dropup");
      optionsAreVisible.value = true;
      selectModelVersionIsVisible.value = false;
    }
    function selectOption(option) {
      console.log(`option → `, option);
      localValue.value = option;
      optionsAreVisible.value = false;
      selectModelVersionIsVisible.value = false;
    }
    function closeDropdown() {
      console.log(`localValue → `, localValue.value);
      console.log("ping");
      optionsAreVisible.value = true
    }
    function clearLocalVal() {
      buttonKey.value++;
      selectModelVersionIsVisible.value = true;
      optionsAreVisible.value = false;
      localValue.value = "";
    }
    return {
      options,
      optionsAreVisible,
      selectModelVersionIsVisible,
      toggleDropup,
      filteredOptions,
      localValue,
      selectOption,
      clearLocalVal,
      buttonKey,
      closeDropdown,
    };
  },
});
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
button
  background: none
  border: none
p
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
::placeholder
  font-style: italic
  line-height: 0
  color: #A5B0CB
._input
  all: unset
  position: relative
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  min-height: 2rem
  min-width: 212px
  background: #161a24
  border-radius: 1rem
  &:hover,
  &:focus
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3867D0

  &-active
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
    // padding-right: 2rem
    &-select-model
      // padding: 6px 0
      color: #A5B0CB
      font-size: 1rem
      font-weight: 300
    &-op-real
      display: flex
      justify-content: center
      align-items: center
      height: 100%
      border-top-left-radius: 1rem
      border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem
      padding: 0 10px
      background: #202634
      font-size: 12px
      font-weight: bold
      letter-spacing: 0.96px
      padding: 8px 10px
      user-select: none
    &-input
      all: unset
      font-size: 14px
      text-align: center
      color: #A5B0CB
      padding: 6px 0px
      padding-right: 2rem
      flex: 1
      border-top-right-radius: 1rem
      border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem
      &:focus::placeholder
        color: transparent
    &-delete
      position: absolute
      bottom: 50%
      transform: translateY(50%)
      right: 0
      display: flex
      justify-content: center
      padding: 0
      padding-right: 8px

._bg-change
  background-color: #202634
._hide
  visibility: hidden
._options
  position: absolute
  bottom: 100%
  left: 30%
  z-index: 100
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  list-style-type: none
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem
  gap: 0.25rem
  background-color: #2C2B30
  border: 1px solid #727275
  border-radius: 0.5rem
._option
  background-color: transparent
  font-size: 0.875rem
  line-height: 1.25rem
  font-weight: 400
  white-space: nowrap
  width: 100%
  &-inner
    width: 100%
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    padding: 0.25rem
    cursor: pointer
    &:hover
      background-color: #3582F5
      border-radius: 0.25rem
    &-model
      font-size: 14px
      color: #fff
      margin-right: 2.5rem
    &-date
      font-size: 12px
      color: #B2B4B9

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active
  transition: opacity 300ms

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to
  opacity: 0
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="_wrapper">
    <SelectModelInput
      v-model="text"
      :models="modelsFromDev"
    />
    <br />
    <span style="color: white">{{ text }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import SelectModelInput from "./components/SelectModelInput.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const text = ref("");
    const modelsFromDev = [
      { model: "Test v4", date: "Jul.5.2022" },
      { model: "Test v5", date: "Jul.6.2022" },
      { model: "Test v6", date: "Jul.8.2022" },
    ];
    return { text, modelsFromDev };
  },
  components: { SelectModelInput },
});
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
body
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
._wrapper
  color: white
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  width: 100vw
  height: 100vh
  background: #283044
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know vue well, but it looks like you're passing blur as a prop to <SelectModelInput> component, so maybe you should somehow execute such passed blur function inside closeDropdown() fn? Look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483447/how-to-pass-blur-into-child-component-vuejs

Also I read that you should use @emit to achieve your goal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676410/blur-on-custom-component

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I had that blur in there just to see if SOMETHING was firing that event. I definitely dont want to pass that up to the parent, but rather handle it the component itself. I removed that one from App.vue so as not to confuse anyone else!

So yeah, the blur event in the component itself not firing when I expect it to is still the issue unfortunately.

Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the options should be tied to clicking on the "Type to Search" `<input>`.  When this `<input>` loses focus then set options visible to false.  Using your code I also had to make functions to separately toggle selectModelVersionIsVisible and optionsAreVisible: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropup-input-forked-rltrb0)

Also regarding one of your other comments, clicking the "X" button can be made to clear localValue by just setting `localValue = ''` on click which is also in my sandbox.  Don't need to use `:key`

Comment: This is awesome! So much more readable. 
I've been messing around trying to get the **Initial State** back after blur as well, but that triggers my `resetInput` event when clicking on an option. Do you have any idea how I can naturally set this component back to it's initial state? I have a quick guard clause in there, but I don't think it's verbose enough. Like `if (localValue.value !== '')` is what I have there, but that doesnt really work the way I envisioned. Perhaps my blur is in the wrong spot or my guard clause needs to be writting better? Thanks again for the help so far!

Comment: also, for some reason it works in your version, but when I put this in my actual code, the blur event happens before the `selectOption` function and just closes the options without the selection happening. Any idea why that isn't consistent across ides?

**EDIT:** I actually made it @mousedown instead of @click and that fixed it! Just for posterities sake:D